# Tag merge request: [performance-counters] and [performancecounter]

Tags: support, retag-request

On Stack Overflow, [performancecounter](/questions/tagged/performancecounter) stands at 358 questions, while [performance-counters](/questions/tagged/performance-counters) (for me a better tag name) stands at 45 questions. Could we have the former merged into the latter?